# Can't read service messages in Redmi Note 3

Tags: android, sms

Have taken all the necessary permissions for reading SMS in android but app is still not able to detect "service messages" on Redmi Note 3. Is there a special permission in Xiaomi devices to read service messages?

Answer (score 5):

If your phone with API 23 or higher (I think the same should work in lower versions also) goto **Settings** -> **Permissions** -> **Other Permissions**. (be sure that you asked required permissions programmatically if you're targeting API 23 or higher version of Android)

There you can find 2 tabs App and Permissions. Select **Permissions** tab under that select **SMS and MMS** option. Now choose your app and Accept/Allow to read Service SMS.

If you're using lower version than 23 use **Security** app (which is built in app Redmi phones) and there you can find Permissions app for the installed apps.

Comment: I want to achieve this programmatically

Comment: I'm also using Redmi Note 3 with API 23. I also faced the same problem but I think there is no fix (programmatically). Because it's a feature in Redmi phones in other brands it works.

Comment: Redmi 3s prime also has the same issue. Above answer solved the problem +1

Comment: Is there any way with which we can detect whether user has a permission or not, so that we can atleast show an alert message regarding the same.

Comment: @MohitPandey try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38309200/5180017) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41061459/5180017) StackOverflow threads. This should work. Best of luck.

Comment: is there any generalized solution for this problem, other than MohitPandey's solution ?.

Comment: @Shashanth As you told **I think there is no fix (programmatically).** then how Freecharge and Paytm can read even if Service SMS denied.

Comment: @GiruBhai Did you try with the solutions given to Mohit Pandey above? I am also facing some problems due to this feature. Not only Freecharge and Paytm other apps also works without any problem.

Comment: @Shashanth **Did you try with the solutions given to Mohit Pandey above?** can you comment link of that answer.

Comment: @Shashanth those link are, to navigate user to service sms screen that's ok but those application read sms even if service sms feature off.

Comment: @Shashanth Have verified that recent message(s) read via BroadcastReceiver even if Service SMS check is off.So it is only problem with reading sms via CONTENT_URI to get all sms type.

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing same problem in my Mi Note 3. No apps reading my messages, every time i need to enter OTP.

I think it is good feature from RedMi.

Now I solved this problem with following steps.

Goto **Setting->Permissions -> Permissions ->** their you select app and accept **Read SMS messages**